# Can not set volume of android app on Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7 P6800 when app is running

Tags: android, settings, android-mediaplayer, volume, soundpool

Is it possible that volume setting works different on different types of android devices ? I tryed to make test app one with mediaPlayer and second with Soundpool. On tablet Galaxy Tab 7.7 P6800 it is not possible to set volume of application using standard volume button (only through system menu change general volume). On other types of devices it works. Is this matter of application or matter of tablet ? Something like volume is blocked.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened in my application too.

```
               AudioManager am;
               am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        int x=20;   //0 to 20 
                       setVolume(x);


                public void setVolume(int x)
                      {
                       am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, x,  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 
                       am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, x,  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 
                       am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, x,  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 
                       am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, x,  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 
                       am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, x,  AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); 

                        }
```

Then provide
                    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
in the android-manifest.